# How to delete a file when deleting a document that contains it in node js and mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user schema that contains some information and a cv path, So I try to delete a document with `findOneAndDelete()` but the cv file doesn't remove alongside the document I've tried the `fs.unlink()` but still doesn't work for me.

Here is my code:

```
     exports.suppStg_control = (req,res,next)=>{
     User.findOneAndDelete({_id:req.params.id})
      .exec()
      .then(doc=>{
      fs.unlink(doc.cv)
      res.status(200).json({message:"user deleted !"});
       }).catch((err)=>{
          throw(err);
       })
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mention the path to the file. You can call fs.unlink(path, callback) for Asynchronous unlink(2) or fs.unlinkSync(path) for Synchronous unlink(2).
Where path is file-path which you want to remove.

Comment: Mentioning the path means like it is in which folder. i.e 'c:/book/discovery.docx'

Comment: i'm using a static path with express.static should i mention it in fs.unlink ??

Comment: Yes you should mention the path of the file